# Summing all values in PHP while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, do-while

Pretty newbie question :/

I have an API that returns values, I just want to get the number of elements in XML but its limited to 30 per query.

```
function SOMEfunction($number){
   $curl = curl_init("*URL*?format=xml&page=" . $number);
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
   $ttn = $xml->count();
   echo "$ttn<br>";
}
```

so,
Since I just want to get the number of elements in XML, i run a short while loop, which i want to sum somehow.

```
$sum=0;
$num=1;
while ($num < 7)
{
   $sum += SOMEfunction($num);
   $num++;
}
echo $sum;
```

the current out put is:

```
30
30
30
30
2
0
0
```

How can i sum them up?

Thanks.

Comment: Your function does not return value. `echo "$ttn<br>";` should be `return $ttn;` Try making that change and combine it with the answer I posted and see if that works.

Comment: You are not making use of the argument that you are passing to your function. Even the syntax for passing the value seems to be incorrect. `VALUE` will be possibly treated as a constant by PHP.

Comment: Where is the value of `$curl` coming from? What does it look like. Maybe you should pass `$curl` as an argument to your function in place of `VALUE`. I am not sure if that will work even.

Comment: Your current code for the function will just echo the value but never assign them to `$sum` variable. Ideally you should not even be getting the output that you are currently getting. It should just be a single value.

Answer (score 3):

`SOMEfunction` should return a value, not print it, as follows:

```
function SOMEfunction($number){
   $curl = curl_init("*URL*?format=xml&page=" . $number);
   $result = curl_exec($curl);
   $xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
   $ttn = $xml->count();
   return $ttn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sum=0;
$num = 1; 
do { 
 $sum += SOMEfunction($num);
 $num++;
} while ( $num > 0 && $num < 7 ); 

echo $sum;
```

This assumes that the rest of your code including `SOMEfunction` is working fine. You can also possibly re-factor the while loop but I am not entirely sure about that.

Another way to do this:

```
$sum=0;
$num=1;
while ($num < 7)
{
   $sum += SOMEfunction($num);
   $num++;
}
echo $sum;
```

Try this and see if it works. If not then I am not sure if your `SOMEfunction` is working correctly.

Comment: Yes, this do while loop looks like a `for($num=1;$num<6;$num++)`. But I think it's a while loop, and the test should be wether SOMEfunction returned 0 or not.

Comment: But how will the sum be obtained in that case. You wanna add another answer with your approach ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
**SOMEfunction** returns each count of XML elements...not 0 always.

when i added the code maximus suggested and removed my echo, i now get the value 0.

Is it possible my initial values were not numbers?

Comment: Try turning your do/while loop into a `for` loop as suggested by @Niols and see what you get ?

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer and see if that works.

Comment: Hi,
Sadly both ways sum still returns 0.

I made a short update to my code above...the way it is actually is, the loop call to the function that contains the XML count, maybe the key is there...

Comment: Can you post your updated code ? Update your question with it ?

Comment: Done...the code is exactly as it is.
last value of the total sum is 0.

Comment: Your function is still not returning a value as I suggested in one of the comments. You also need to change `function SOMEfunction(number)` to `function SOMEfunction($number)` and actually make use of `$number` somewhere in that function.

Comment: Yeah, your function is printing instead of returning. I don't need to post an other answer if you update yours ;)

Comment: Yep,
edited.

the only thing missing is the SUM, which is still 0.

Comment: YAYYYYYYYYY :)
Changed to return :) it works.

Awesome...thanks guys :)